# Wordpress remove content from certain posts

Tags: wordpress, posts

i need to remove a div from certain posts in my wordpress template, i know the id's to the posts i need to do that, can someone help me with this?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
if(!is_page( array(10, 20, 30) ) ){
    // Your Div here
}
```

Basically, if the post in this case does NOT equal 10, 20 or 30, then show the div. If it IS 10, 20 or 30, then the Div won't display.